# How to read Okta SAML assertion response on receiving web application (service provider)

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta

I am working on using SAML2.0 and integrate with Okta. I tried using spring-security exmaple given on the okta site and it is working fine. Now I am trying to add my web application to okat and when I initiate or click on my web application in okta dashboard I want to see what SAML assertion is sent to service provider. I want to read user's first name , lastname on lets say index.jsp page in my web app.

I see on my tomcat logs following response printed.

INFO  org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule - Validation of protocol message signature succeeded, message type: {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}Response

But when I try to get the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() object in index.jsp I get null.

The user is created in Okta and assigned to application. But this user does not exist in my web application database. All I want to see is the user created in Okta is sent to my web app. I just want to read the metadat like firstname , lastname etc. Is it possible? Has someone tried it?

My web app is already using CasAuthentication.

Comment: Forgot to mention that when I log in with existing user and try accessing index.jsp, then I do see SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() object created but it shows it is authenticated with casAuthentication whcih is obvisous. But not sure how I can read the user details coming from Okta before loging in SP web app.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. Posting here for the peers who may be facing similar issue.

Basically if you are using more than 1 authentication manager, make sure youar alias names are different and you are referring to correct alias name in the saml beans in "ref" section. Mine started working fine once I corrected it.